# Robotframework-rabbitmq not working with newest robotframework library

Tags: python, rabbitmq, robotframework

my `requirements.txt` file looks like this:

```
robotframework==4.0.3
robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0
selenium==3.141.0
robotframework-excellib==2.0.1
robotframework-csvlib==1.0.2
robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary==0.5.5
robotframework-jsonlibrary==0.3.1
robotframework-jsonvalidator==2.0.0
robotframework-requests==0.9.1
robotframework-openpyxllib==0.7
robotframework-difflibrary==0.1.0
robotframework-xvfb==1.2.2
robotframework-archivelibrary==0.4.1
robotframework-databaselibrary==1.2.4
robotframework-rabbitmq==3.0.0
pymysql
urllib3==1.26.5
RESTinstance
requests==2.25.1
robotframework-pabot
```

When I was running `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get an outcome as follows:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 12), -r requirements.txt (line 13), -r requirements.txt (line 15), -r requirements.txt (line 4), -r requirements.txt (line 6), -r requirements.txt (line 7), -r requirements.txt (line 8), -r requirements.txt (line 9) and robotframework==4.0.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested robotframework==4.0.3
    robotframework-excellib 2.0.1 depends on robotframework>=3.0.3
    robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary 0.5.5 depends on robotframework
    robotframework-jsonlibrary 0.3.1 depends on robotframework>=3.0
    robotframework-jsonvalidator 2.0.0 depends on robotframework>=3.0.1
    robotframework-requests 0.9.1 depends on robotframework
    robotframework-xvfb 1.2.2 depends on robotframework
    robotframework-archivelibrary 0.4.1 depends on robotframework
    robotframework-rabbitmq 3.0.0 depends on robotframework==3.0.4
```

I take it as a problem with last row - `rabbitmq 3.0.0` is not really working with the newest version `robotframework==4.0.3`.

Loosing it by setting `robotframework-rabbitmq` without version causes neverending downloading dependencies, stucked for hours like:

```
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Downloading six-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Downloading six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Downloading six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of robotframework-pythonlibcore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting robotframework-pythonlibcore>=2.1.0
  Downloading robotframework_pythonlibcore-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of six to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Downloading robotframework_pythonlibcore-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. If you want to abort this run, you can press Ctrl + C to do so. To improve how pip performs, tell us what happened here: https://pip.pypa.io/surveys/backtracking
  Downloading robotframework_pythonlibcore-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of robotframework-seleniumlibrary to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting robotframework-seleniumlibrary>=3.0.0
  Downloading robotframework_seleniumlibrary-5.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of robotframework-pythonlibcore to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /packages/1b/a3/f712ffbad35b177af1c91e8ba58ec56a34a6dd61ce6348d779b4951482df/robotframework_seleniumlibrary-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Downloading robotframework_seleniumlibrary-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
...
```

(it's not the issue with my internet, as I checked)

Why is it not working with newest robotframework? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Remove "Selenium2Library" first - it should not be used anymore. It is just meta package that will pull robotframework-seleniumnlibrary anyway.. Report back afterwards.

Comment: @rasjani thanks for poinitng it out. Nevertheless, I still can see when I'm loosing version name from RF it stills download 3.0.4 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/peterservice-rnd/robotframework-rabbitmq/issues/8), looks like Rabbitmq library can be installed only with `3.0.4` version.

In [this](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot/issues/377) topic it was suggested to install rabbit first and then after it run `pip install --upgrade robotframework`, which worked pretty well.

So, install RF==3.0.4, install RMQ library and then upgrade FR to newest version.